# Pass "IS NULL" via parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have 5 textboxes:

```
<TextBox Name="txbFirstName" />
<TextBox Name="txbLastName" />
<TextBox Name="txbCity" />        
<TextBox Name="txbAddress" />
<TextBox Name="txbPhone" />
```

I want to generate simple SELECT statements using the textbox inputs. To do this I am using parameters and AddWithValue:

```
database.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName AND City = @City AND Address = @Address AND Phone = @Phone;");
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txbFirstName.Text);
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txbLastName.Text);
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txbCity.Text);
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txbAddress.Text);
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txbPhone.Text);
```

Now this works just fine, but what I want to do is that if textbox input is empty to handle it with NULL. But as far as I know one can't use "= NULL" in query, instead "IS NULL" should be used, meaning I can't write something like this:

```
if (txbCity.Text == "")
    database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", null);
else
    database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txbCity.Text);
```

Is it possible to pass "IS NULL" to a parameter with code? So if txbCity and txbAddress were null, for example:

- First Name = John
- Last Name = Doe
- City = ""
- Address = ""
- Phone = 812-393-8144

I would want my query to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE FirstName = "John" AND LastName = "Doe" AND City IS NULL AND Address IS NULL AND Phone = "812-393-8144";
```

Comment: tried [DbNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: First of all, [stop using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Second - you can pass `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @SeM What should I be using instead of AddWithValue? I am still learning and pretty noob at this for now.

Comment: @JohnDoe For example: [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/)

Comment: @JohnDoe frankly, I'd say "let Dapper deal with it" :) dealing with the peculiarities of the ADO.NET API isn't a great use of anyone's time; I *strongly* recommend letting Dapper deal with almost all of that stuff, but... I'm biased (it is data access tool we wrote for Stack Overflow itself)

Comment: Example using dapper, for completeness: `var customers = connection.Query<Customer>("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE ...", new { FirstName = "...", LastName = "...", /* etc */ });` - it deals with your parameters (including the peculiar `null` handling), executes the query, and processes the results - all very efficiently

Comment: @MarcGravell - totally can't be read as you being bias - `all very efficiently` :)

Comment: @RandRandom that's simply factual - a lot of effort has been invested to keep overhead minimal - we *really, really* care about that kind of thing here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically: no.

Unless you have disabled ANSI NULL syntax (please don't do that), you need *different SQL* to test for `NULL`. A common trick (easy to write, but not very efficient) is to cheat with:

```sql
WHERE (FirstName = @FirstName OR (@FirstName IS NULL AND FirstName IS NULL))
AND (LastName = @LastName OR (@LastName IS NULL AND LastName IS NULL))
-- etc x5
```

(or whatever test you want to perform for nulls) - and use something like:

```cs
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txbFirstName.Text.DBNullIfEmpty());
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txbLastName.Text.DBNullIfEmpty());
// etc x5
```

where `DBNullIfEmpty` would look something like:

```cs
internal static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static object DBNullIfEmpty(this string value)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return DBNull.Value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, adding "OR IS NULL" for each parameter seems to work properly, thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe note: I changed that bit a little ... it kinda depends on whether you expect "parameter is null" to mean "don't enforce this condition" vs "enforce that the column is null"; `(Foo = @foo OR @foo IS NULL)` does the first; `(Foo = @foo OR (Foo IS NULL AND @foo IS NULL))` does the second

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method for AddWithValue() and pass an extra third parameter as what value u want when the actual value is NULL

```
public static class SqlParameterCollectionExtensions {
    public static SqlParameter AddWithValue(this SqlParameterCollection target, string parameterName, object value, object nullValue) {
        if (value == null) {
            return target.AddWithValue(parameterName, nullValue);
        }
        return target.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
    }
}
```

And later call it like this

```
database.sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txbCity.Text, "IS NULL");
```

Answer (score -1):

The value of the parameter corresponding to a `NULL` value in SQL Server database is `DBNull.Value`.

```
Parameters.Add(“@NAME”, SqlDbType.<type>).Value = argument == null ? DBNull.Value : argument;
```

Comment: I don't think that will work properly, because `FirstName = NULL` will always be false in sql, afaik (and tested) it had to be `FirstName IS NULL`, so the whole approach won't work. OP needs to separate the null cases explicitly.

Comment: I’m only answering to the relevant question he asked, meaning how to pass c# null as a parameter in SQL. How to deal with the logic of his program isn’t relevant.

Comment: Seriously? Do you really think that was the _relevant_ question?

Comment: Ah (after your edit), there are some more relevant parts, like you don't use `AddWithValue` and provide a type. Nonetheless to compare columns against `NULL` you need a different sql syntax than `=` or `<>`.